# Failed to connect to port 8080: Connection refused Error number: 7 (cURL)

Tags: php, linux, curl

I have the following code -

```
$url = 'http://52.77.156.123:8080/LebuPay/check-payment';

$ch = curl_init($url);

$data = array(
"successURL"  =>  'http://jsonviewer.stack.hu',
"failureURL"  =>   'http://jsonviewer.stack.hu',
"amount"  => $amount,
"orderTransactionID"  => $order_id,
"firstName" =>   "",
"lastName"  =>  "",
"email" => "",
"mobileNumber"  => "",
"accessKey" =>  "some_random_key"
);

$jsonEncode = json_encode($data);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonEncode);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$result = json_decode($result, true);

echo "Error CURL: " . curl_error($ch) . " \nError number: " . 
curl_errno($ch);

curl_close($ch);


$token = $result['token'];
header("location: http://52.77.156.123:8080/LebuPay/execute-payment?token=$token");
```

The code works on my localhost but when I upload it on the server (Godaddy linux). It gives me error "Failed to connect to 52.77.156.123 port 8080: Connection refused Error number: 7"

The API I'm trying to get response from is hosted on AWS.

Any idea how I can solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: "Connection refused" seems like `ECONNREFUSED` which is typical when there's no one listening for connections on the other end.

Comment: As for a possible reason, in `$url` you use port 8000, but in the `location` header at the end you use port 8080. Which one is it?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sorry, the port is 8080 and I've fixed it but it stil shows the same error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the problem occurs when you changed the server, I would suspect that the problem is the outgoing server blocking the port.

[This, admittedly old, forum post](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?623004-Curl-access-to-alternate-port) says:

> I don't know if it applies to anything other than shared hosting, but Godaddy shared hosting has all outgoing ports other than 80 blocked by their firewall

and

> The problem is that Godaddy shared hosting will not let you make requests from your site that go to any port other than 80.
>
> It's like having a house where all of the doors and windows, except the front door, are welded shut.

and

> Talked to Godaddy Support and was told port 8080 is blocked, even on their dedicated servers.

This might have changed in the meantime, but since you are experiencing the problem I don't think it has.

---

Possible solutions:

- Don't use awful hosting (Godaddy has a terrible reputation)
- Somehow persuade Godaddy to open up the port
- Find a proxy that lets you use port 80 to get the request outside of Godaddy's network

Comment: Thanks Quentin. You're correct, the problem is with the Godaddy server. Because I've just tested it on Hostgator and it works there fine.

Comment: Do you think changing the port from 80 to something else would work? Since changing Godaddy at the moment is a bit difficult.

Comment: The linked forum post says that only port 80 is allowed. Changing to anything that is not port 80 would not work.

Comment: So there's a chance if I can change the port 8080 to 80?

Comment: Yes. Only port 80 is allowed.