# Why curl to another server dont work in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, curl

I am working on codeigniter and I am doing a POST request curl for another project that is located on another server that is on another network.

This is my code.
controller from my webpage

```
function submit_form() {
    error_log("data: ". $_POST);
    $data = $this->input->post('data');

    $data = json_decode($data,true);
    error_log("data id: ".$data['idParceiro']);
    // where are we posting to?
    $url = 'http://mywebdomain/ncsync/Sync/getLogin';

    $fields = array('idParceiro' => $data['idParceiro']);

    // build the urlencoded data
    $postvars = http_build_query($fields);

    // open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,    1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);

    // execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

The error_log on the server that receives the post is not being printed, hence I conclude that nothing is coming.

this is my .htaccess in my server that receive the request in folder /application

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>

    Require all denied

</IfModule>

<IfModule !authz_core_module>

    Deny from all

</IfModule>
```

Note: This works on localhost when I am on the same network as the server to which I am requesting.
Can help me?

Comment: `$url = 'http://mywebdomain/ncsync/Sync/getLogin';` are you sure that's OK? it seems to be missing the domain extension

Comment: did you try $error = curl_error($ch); ? see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Comment: Is the `Deny from all` stopping it?

Comment: I have this .htaccess in other service and work fine

Comment: @vickel Curl error: Failed to connect to myDomain port 8080: Connection refused

Comment: are you on a shared server, if so which one?

Comment: @Vickel is a shared server

Comment: would rather not share the ip/domain, it will even be necessary?

Comment: i use apache with xampp

Comment: I didn't ask for the ip/domain, just the server company, anyway have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46826311/failed-to-connect-to-port-8080-connection-refused-error-number-7-curl

Comment: its is an internal server